# Display PHP script in HTML on same page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have almost 0 experience and knowledge with anything front end, and I also have 0 experience with PHP. But I am trying to study it on my own.

This time, my concern is that, how am I gonna make it possible for me to click a button, and display the output in that same page?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    echo "hello world";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Manual')">Manual</button>
        </div>

        <div id="Manual" class="tabcontent">
            <table>
                <tr><td>
                    <h4>Targeted IP/s:</h4>
                    <tbody id="online"></tbody>
            </td></tr>
          </table>
        </div>

        <script>
        // Call PHP code here
        // var res = sample.php;
        $("#online").html(res);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My goal here is basically clicking the button,

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Manual')">Manual</button>
```

And display the  above just below the said button. Not in a new or different page.

Comment: For starters, you might want to read about forms which you can read more about here => https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Your button should have an on click event which will write the text just below it . Open a div just below it and write it there . You can do it using JQuery or through PHP by calling the same page inside form action and passing the text via a text box . Now on page load catch the text and display it in the required div .

Comment: @PHPWeb - Hi. Is it okay if you show me how it is done and post it as an answer? I would appreciate.

Comment: basically your request is named as AJAX, so learn it from any website or w3schools, learn pure ajax and then learn jQuery ajax.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you got at least two methods to achieve this : `$.ajax` and `$.get` 
the two methods use ajax to asynchronously load content or achieve different operations in the back-end.In your case the `$.get` will be sufficient .But you need to rewrite your javaScript specifically your openTab method to use ajax call to load the content before display it.This is a good way to achieve it .But if your goal is to write the content of a PHP script directly in your javaScript before loading the whole page ,it is possible too but instead of 
`var res=sample.php` which would only write sample.php in your page

you must use something like

```
<?php
include('sample.php');
?>
```

directly in your tab

or if sample.php use the return statement to return a value

```
<?php
$res=include('sample.php');
?>
var res=<?php echo $res ?>
```

and use in your opentab function

```
$("#online").html(res);
```